# FTP  URL to Server

Tags: ftp, wget

I have a website that I need to FTP files onto. The files that need to be uploaded are already store on the cloud with mediafire. Is there a way I can use Filezilla to upload from that download link? I'm basically asking, "What is the wget version for ftp"?

Comment: Do you have shell access to the ftp server? If not, you'll have to download from mediafire and upload via ftp.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can use Filezilla to upload from that download link?

Yes, as it can be used as an FTP client.  You need the FTP account's password, of course.

> What is the wget version for ftp?

[**cURL**](http://curl.haxx.se/)

I'm not sure what the relationship is between those questions, and I don't have any experience with MediaFire.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking if you can do a 2 stage process:

```
   1.  Download files from media server to a local copy using HTTP
   2.  Then upload those files to another FTP site
```

Yes, you can do that with a Curl script.

If you're a more advanced user, and both remote systems are on windows, then you can use WinSCP + Filezilla Server  to accomplish a automatic site mirroring scenerio.

If it is less than 2GB of files, you could also do it with Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoFileMove](http://www.autofilemove.com) to do that, Check my answer there https://superuser.com/a/636421/927